# Thymeleaf utility for System.currentTimeMillis()

Tags: java, date, thymeleaf, milliseconds

Is there any way to use [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()) as utility in thymeleaf?
Thymeleaf has [dates](https://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/2.1.6.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/expression/Dates.html) utility for dates(Date) operations [`${#dates.millisecond(date)}`]. 
But it doesn't have utility to directly access currentTimeMillis without passing date as an argument.

Is there any way to access [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()) utility without having custom dialect utility/expression?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the static call to `${T(java.lang.System).currentTimeMillis()}`.

Otherwise, you have `${execInfo.now}` available to you, but that could be slightly off since it would be the time at which processing the template starts.